# "Task" doesn't actually chain transactions

Tags: pg-promise

Maybe I'm not using/understanding the "task" object correctly. When I do the following:

```
   return await db.tx(async (task) => {
      
      await.task.oneOrNone('INSERT INTO message (body) VALUES ('test') RETURNING id)
 
      await task.oneOrNone('INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('bob') RETURNING id)

    });
```

If the first insert fails I would expect for the second insert to fail. This however doesn't not seem to be the case. Please help me understand how to use task correctly from this example.

Comment: If the first insert fails, it throws an error, which terminates the transaction, and the second query does not execute. Why would you expect it otherwise? `If the first insert fails I would expect for the second insert to fail` - this doesn't make sense why the code would keep executing after failing.